# Hibernate runs all tables doing a simple login

Tags: java, hibernate

I have done some maintenances in a web system, this system was done in Java, Struts2 and Hibernate 3. One of the items that my customer asked me urgently was to correct the Login, because it's very slow.

I could identify when the user does the login, the Hibernate generates many queries on the database in different tables which does not have relation with login.

My relationship are three tables: User, Student, Teacher

Student

- ID
- Name

Teacher

- ID
- Name

User

- ID
- Login
- Password

Every time that a student does a login the query check if it's the correct Login and Password and if the ID exists in a Student table. As you can see there is no foreign key ID, as for example, ID_USER in a Student table.

My Query:

```
Student student =(Student)session.createCriteria(Student.class)
.add( Property.forName("login").eq(login) )
.add( Property.forName("password").eq(password) )
.setMaxResults(1)
.uniqueResult();
```

- Student inherits from User...

My User.hbm.xml

...

```
<class name="com.xxx.User" table="TBL_USERS" discriminator-value="0" lazy="true">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
     <generator class="sequence">
         <param name="sequence">seq_users</param>
     </generator>
    </id>

    <discriminator column="TYPE" insert="true" />

    <subclass name="com.xxx.Student" discriminator-value="1" lazy="true">
      <join table="TBL_STUDENTS">
         <key column="ID"/>
            <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
      </join>
     </subclass>

     <subclass name="com.xxx.Teacher" discriminator-value="2" lazy="true">
        <join table="TBL_TEACHERS">
           <key column="ID" />
               <property name="name" column="NAME"  />
        </join>
     </subclass>
```

...

In my Hibernate log many strange queries, like bellow:

It's happening in more than 20 different tables and repeating all the times, because that, the login action is slow. But I don't know why it's happening, I don't have much experience with Hibernate.

Hibernate:

```
select
      exerc0_.ID_CLASS as ID6_1_,
      exerc0_.ID as ID1_,
      exerc0_.ID as ID14_0_,
      exerc0_.DATE_ENT as DATA2_14_0_,
        exerc0_.TITLE as TITTLE14_0_,
        exerc0_.TEXT as TEXT14_0_,
        exerc0_.TYPE_EXERC as TYPE5_14_0_,
        exerc0_.ID_CLASS as ID6_14_0_ 
    from
        TBL_EXERC exerc0_ 
    where
        exerc0_.ID_CLASS=?
```

What could be happening?

Comment: are there any many-to-one or bag/set/list mappings in user.hbm? i suspect that lazyloading is accidentally disabled#

Comment: Only this, but now I am trying change the way to do the relationship. Because I cannot understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just to not leave this question open forever.
The problem was fixed many time ago, but I forgot completely to reply.
I had to enable few lazy-loadings and make sure to choose LIST instead SET in few other places. Seemed more performatic with LIST.

@Firo was right in somehow.